# lightsail app not appearing on aws console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I cannot see my lightsail instance at console : https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?region=eu-west-1

I can view my lightsail instance at https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/webapp/home/instances

Should lightsail instances be viewable at aws console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightsail resources are not view-able in the main AWS console. They only show up in the Lightsail console.

This applies to Lightsail VPS instances, databases, and DNS zones.